# Change Magento 2 Paypal Logo on Checkout Step 2

Tags: magento2.2

I want to change the Paypal logo on Magento 2 Checkout second step. 
I have found that file to do the modification is,

> vendor/magento/module-paypal/view/frontend/web/template/payment/paypal-express.html

I don't want to modify core files and i have done the override inside

> design/frontend/Vendor/mytheme/Magento_Paypal/web/template/payment/paypal-express.html

but it doesn't do any effect on frontend.

Which is the correct way to `override Paypal module`?

Comment: did you ran setup:upgrade command after changes?

Comment: Yes , i have run php bin/magento setup:upgrade and also php bin/magento cache:clean but still the same

Comment: Vendor_Module/view/frontend/web/template/payment/paypal-express.html

Try this

Comment: Have you tried the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom module & override the templates using

> Vendor_Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        'Magento_Paypal/template/payment/paypal-express.html': 'Vendor_Module/template/payment/paypal-express.html'
    }
}
```

};

**Then placed the templates under**

> Vendor_Module/view/frontend/web/template/payment/paypal-express.html

Comment: Hi @Aditya Shah , thanks for responding. I created the custom module and added the files as described above but now the paypal payment method is disappeared from checkout

Comment: @Krisi please run below commands

Comment: rm -Rf var/cache/* rm -Rf var/generation/*

Comment: Because we made changes in require.js

Comment: php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php -f bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: i tried all the ways of cache  cleaning but it is still the  same, Paypal disappeared

Comment: Okay no worries, will find a solution.

Answer (score -1):

after your change, please run command: 
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: thanks for responding. i have run all the above commands but still no change